# Is passing user input into python subprocess dangerous?

Tags: python

So, my code something as such

```
tsharkCall = ["C:\\Program Files\\Software\\binary.exe", userinput]
process = subprocess.Popen(tsharkCall, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None)
output, error = process.communicate()
streams = output.split("\r\n")
```

Note that `binary.exe` is some binary executable which processes the user-input.
Some examples are `binary.exe filename.txt` or `binary.exe <some input>`

Considering here, I have left `shell=False` into `Popen` does this impose a security risk such as command injection. Like let's consider whether someone injects as `\r\ndir` or `%0d%0amalicious_command` then would it break and run a separate command (i.e command injection). I tried using CRLF to escape but `Popen` wouldn't let arbitrary command work. Good for me.

But is using such method to execute userinput a wise way in production too ?

Comment: First, is it safe to pass user input as an argument to `binary.exe`? If, say, it’s first argument is a filename that you’re expecting to be a relative path but the user can send you `C:\Windows\System\importantthing` and get a dump of your password database back…

Comment: Second, on Windows, `subprocess` has to create a command-line string even when you give it a list, because that’s how the OS works. It passes that to the `CreateProcess` API, not the shell, so simple hacks like `\r\ncommand` or `|command` won’t work, but you should read the remarks section of the docs on that function for every version of Windows you care about. (I can tell you that I’m pretty sure it’s safe for your use case, but you should read for yourself rather than trusting me…)

Comment: @abarnert : Yes, Safe to pass any arbitrary file input.

Comment: Does `shell=True` or `shell=False` would make any difference @abarnert . A better practice ?

Comment: I don’t understand what your first comment means. For the second one, `shell=False` is the default, and it’s what you should always be using unless you actually need shell features (like piping, calling builtins commands of the shell, etc.—and even then you can almost always rewrite your code to not need them). The docs explain this, and you should read them, but you’re already doing the right thing here.

Comment: The first comment was a response to your `First, is it safe to pass user input as an argument to binary.exe?` . Relative Path Traversal is not possible. Thanks for the clarification anyways